# Как показать изображение во Vue.js файле (Ruby on Rails Active Storage)

Tags: vue.js, ruby-on-rails

Не могу вывести изображение, загруженное ActiveRecord.

В контроллере

```
  def attach_main_pic(book)
    book.image.attach(book_params[:image])
  end
```

В сериалайзере

```
  def image_url
    rails_blob_url(object.image, only_path: true) if object.image.attached?
  end
```

В vue файле пытаюсь вывести изображение `q-img(v-bind:src="props.row.image_url" style="height: 140px; max-width: 150px")`

Лог сервера
[Ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSteK.png)

Comment: Попробуйте метод url_for вместо rails_blob_url

Comment: Нет, пробовал 
`rails_blob_path`
`rails_blob_url`
`rails_representation_url`
`service_url`
и `url_for`